# Whatsapp Webhook for Development

Tags: facebook, whatsapp, whatsapi

Possibly a dumb question but I have not been able to find an answer to this. I am starting out with Whatsapp API and I have my Webhook running correctly in localhost using an ngrok tunnel. Thing is, I will now push to production and for sure I will need to do some modifications to the webhook in the future.

In the developers.facebook platform, I can only see the option of configuring just one webhook. Am I missing something here? I feel like my current alternative of creating another facebook app just for development is not the way to go.

Thanks

Got my webhook running. I just thought there might be a way of configuring a development webhook and a production webhook or something similar

Comment: Have you checked if you are able to configure a different webhook URL, when you create a _test app_ version of your existing app? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-apps That's kind of the middle ground, it will be using a different app ID, but is still closely tied to your "real" one.